# Why is min(a,b) not working but max(a,b) working?

Tags: python, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython, neptune

I’m writing a very simple Python code which requires the minimum of two integers, so when I do `min(2,5)` I get `TypeError: 'Operator' object is not callable` error. However, when I do `max(2,5)` I get the correct output. I am trying this in a cell in Python notebook with Python3.
The code I'm trying to execute:

```
def split(node_list):
    k, m = divmod(len(node_list), 5)
    chunks = [node_list[i*quo+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(5)]
    return chunks
```

From my research, some posts mentioned not to have any other variables named "min". Initially I was confused because I had no other variable or function named "min". Then I realized the the file I'm using is also executing code using `gremlin_python` library that has `min()` in-built function which is used to query Neptune graphs, and that's probably why I'm seeing this error.
Could someone please let me know how I could explicitly ensure that the code used Python's in-build min()?
Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Edit: Gremlin imports i'm using

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.driver import serializer
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.driver.aiohttp.transport import AiohttpTransport
```

Comment: are you using a starred import? e.g. `from gremlin_python import *`? The solution is *not to do that*

Comment: in any case, somewhere, you have assigned to the variable `min`, whether it was with an assignment statement or with an import. we need a [mcve], or else we can only guess

Comment: So you should *really* fix whatever it is that is causing it. In any case, you can use `import builtins` and `builtins.min` to access the built-in `min`. But again, you **really** should fix whatever is causing this. It is a bad sign that you don't know where a variable is being assigned another value you didnt expect.

Comment: The Gremlin Python function can be referenced using `min_()` - Which version of Gremlin Python are you using? Functions like `min` were removed from Gremlin Python's static definitions some while back to avoid just these types of collision.

Comment: I'm using gremlin python 3.6

Comment: And how are you importing from gremlin? Its "min" function is going to be somewhere in the gremlin namespace, and it shouldn't be shadowing the builtin `min` unless you've imported it.

Comment: I'm also doing `statics.load_statics(globals())` so it looks like its importing gremlin's "min" function from there. I'm not sure if there's a better way to import these

Comment: Ah yes - don't do that! I think at some point the TinkerPop docs recommended it. But it's best not to. If you do for some reason need to keep doing that you will want to still `delete` the conflicting ones. But the best practice is to use the Gremlin specific function names when using Python as they are designed just to avoid such conflicts by adding an underscore to the name of any that do.

Comment: using Gremlin specific function names worked, thank you! @KelvinLawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a Gremlin Python step or function name collides with a Python reserved word, you can use an underscore after the function name. For example in gremlin Python you would use `min_()` .

In earlier versions of the TinkerPop documentation it was suggested to do `statics.load_statics(globals())` which actually can cause exactly the issues you encountered. I would avoid messing with `statics` and just use the Gremlin form with the underscores.